# How to terminate wires?

Tags: electrical, wire

I'm trying to terminate some wires after removing a light fitting. Will it be fairly safe to terminate the wires using screw terminal blocks like [these](http://www.homebase.co.uk/en/homebaseuk/30a-6-way-connector-strip-863908)?

Comment: Are you talking about AC power? The link you provided is showing price in pounds. In general *(or at least in the US), you have to use an approved UL device for making wiring connections and terminations in electrical boxes. While people often cut and then electrical tape unused wires, its not correct to do so. The device you link is not designed for AC and is also still "open" thus not technically a termination. If you are doing something as a hobbyist, with low current power, in an unregulated by any code context, yes you can use that.

Comment: Are they not designed for AC? It's just that we'll be painting the ceiling with light fittings disconnected. I thought it'd be wise to manage the dangling wires.

Comment: My bad on the comment portion of it not being designed for ac. I looked at it briefly and actually thought it was a basic hobby shop term strip.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Will it be fairly safe to terminate the wires using screw terminal blocks like these?**

### Permanently

Although UK connector blocks of that type are rated for 400V AC 30A. As far as I know, any unused wires should be either removed completely or alternatively, disconnected at *both ends*, and connected to ground at both ends. This is so that a circuit breaker trips immediately if the wires are ever accidentally made live. All connections must remain accessible via a cover plate, you can't just plaster over where the light fitting used to be.

One important objective is to avoid creating an invisible and illegal lethal electrical hazard for the next family that move into your home.

### Temporarily

What you propose is perfectly sensible for a temporary arrangement during painting of a wall or ceiling. Temporary in the sense that normal arrangements will be restored within a day or so.

You don't need a 30A connector for a lighting circuit, a smaller 6A connector is fine for a typical UK 6A lighting circuit. This is enough to ensure that the breaker trips before the connector catches fire in the event of a mishap such as accidentally flooding the connector with conductive paint.

The purpose of the covering is to keep the liquid paint out, so it probably doesn't need to be electricians tape. That would probably be convenient though.

Comment: Would it be acceptable to use one of those blocks, screw the wires in and seal the block with electrical tape? We're just taking the light fittings off for painting. Also, we'll keep the breaker off.

Comment: If this is just a temporary thing, I would use electrical tape or standard wire nuts for the gauge wire you are using. the terminal strip you posted doesn't actually stop something or someone from coming into contact with the live wire (via a srew head or terminal lug) granted they'd have to poke something small into it, but still could. Plus it costs like 8$ US.... why spend the money on it? Electrical tape costs 99 cents. and a bag of wire nuts shouldnt be much (not to mention if you took lights down didnt it aleardy have wire nuts in it? I can't think fo reason to want to use that block

Comment: @noybman I don't think we have wire nuts in the UK though.

Comment: @John, what you propose is perfectly sensible. I'll update my answer to address this.

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick I thought electrical tape might be needed to cover up the screw which is conductive.

Comment: @John, the screws are recessed into the plastic, you can't accidentally touch them with fingers. If you are poking at the things with pointy metal implements, you are just as likely to make contact through the two openings for the wires (whose metal parts are also recessed). Electricians tape doesn't offer a lot of mechanical protection. But it won't do any harm (other than leave a sticky mess when removed).